# Is there some Javascript libraries for jelly animation?

Tags: javascript

Since I've been working with Javascript, I haven't found any libraries for jelly animation that would replace big, long `@keyframes` with one function. Does anybody know something about it?

Comment: Have a look at bouncejs.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [jelly.js](https://github.com/lmgonzalves/jelly)? Don't know is it requires your needs, but looks really easy to use.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use it.